# Parse object containing array elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, ios8

I have a Parse object called `Recipes` and a column called `ingredients`, which is an array. I want to query my object list and retrieve a recipe based on some ingredients that I select.

If I use the `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:` message on the query object, I will get recipes with more ingredients. Also, `whereKey:containedIn:` does not solve my problem. The retrieved objects should have an array of ingredients containing all my selected ingredients or only some of them. It should never have more ingredients than those I've selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: That does not really make sense from a logical point of view... why would you have to specify ALL ingredients to get the recipe?

Comment: I want to retrieve the recipes that I can make using some ingredients (available in my house at that moment). I don't want to retrieve any recipes that requires more ingredients than I currently have available.

Comment: Can't you just fetch all the results for that ingredient set and then use some logic to filter out the ones with extra ingredients in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra column to your recipe table "array count" for the number of ingredients in the recipe. Then do a multiple query:

```
[query whereKey:ingredients containsAllObjectsInArray:ingredientsArray];
[query whereKey: arrayCount equalTo:[ingredientsArray count]];
```

That way you are only returning things with the same number of ingredients and all the ones you listed.

Comment: Great, yeah parse has some weird limitations. Usually means you have to find a way around it changing your data model up a bit. glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do - `whereKey:notContainedIn:` for all the rest of the `ingredients` (the ingredients this user **doesn't** have). and than the user will get only `ingredients` he has.

Comment: That would be a valid workaround but I wouldn't want to send over the network all the ingredients (since there are a lot of them and I wouldn't want my app to use internet data in vain).